# Horizontally aligning position:relative divs (CSS)

Tags: css, html, alignment

I would like to do this from my website here: http://project.jazzassite.tk
and be able to place the contents into a div that I can center or do whatever I want with them. The only problem is, If I float it, it doesn't work, and if I use position:relative They create a stair case effect.

I was hoping I would be able to do this purely with CSS, and not use any tables, ect.

Any help appreciated,
Jazza

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to center the `navigate` div which contains all the 6 children?  If so, this should work:

```
#navigate {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -540px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

The margin-left is the half the width of the contents and then made negative.  The margin-right is half the height of the contents and then made negative.  This will vertically and horizontally center your objects.  Is this what you're looking for or did I miss the point?

Comment: If the answer helped you, it'd help me and other people who view this question if you marked it correct!  Glad to hear I could be of assistance Jazza!